# Super simple Nagios alternative?

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

After having used Nagios for many years, I tried M/Monit, and it is mostly what I want, but still it lacks the option to customize the format of the notification emails sent by M/Monit, which makes it unusable.

I have checked https://alternativeto.net/software/nagios/ , but they are not simple at all.

**Question**

Does there exist a super simple alternative to Nagios (or M/Monit)? All I really need is something central that can send out an email when NRPE or Monit gives an alert or they aren't heard from in X seconds.

It doesn't even need to have a web interface, some sort of command line is fine.

Answer (score 1):

try zenoss.
To listen nrpe and forward email , you can write a simple script in python with nagios nerd (Nagios Event Radio Dispatcher). With nerd your script wait for an nagios's events and after you can perform some task and finally sent email.

Comment: Where can I find NERD? Is it part of Nagios? Iwould prefer if I didn't had to install Nagios if possible.

Comment: yes, is part of Nagios Core >=4 . With nerd, you don't need execute task from nagios's  gui. https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/whatsnew.html#nerd